# Is there a performance difference between int i =0 and int i = default(int)?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I was creating an integer and i wanted to instantiate it with 0  before working with.

I wrote firstly

```
int i = default(int);
```

then i removed it to replace with the other one which is

```
int i = 0;
```

I would like to know if my choice is the best in *mini mini* performance.
Will the default() function increase the instructions at compile time?

Comment: And beyond micro-optimization there always is nano-optimization...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, they are resolved at compile time and produce the same IL. Value types will be `0` (or `false` if you have a bool, but that's still 0) and reference types are `null`.

Comment: Is that correct in general? What if I have a generic method like `public T GetDefault<T>() { return default(T); }` - it cannot be resolved in compile time. In fact, I can use it with types that don't even exist yet. Anyway, the real answer is - if this silly little change makes a difference for you, C# is probably too slow anyway for your needs.

Comment: That can be resolved at compile time, as `T` will be known/inferred.

Comment: @George - That isn't the interesting case. What if you use `GetDefault` as part of a compiled assembly? `default(T)` isn't compiled again or optimized in that case (OK, it is by the JIT, but that's another question)

Comment: @George not true. What if the generic method is a public method in an assembly that's referenced by another project, and code in the hosting project passes one of its private types to the generic method? No way of knowing what's going to be passed to said method when the assembly is being built.

Answer (score 4):

Marlon's answer is technically correct, but there should be a clear semantic difference between each option.

```
int i = 0;
```

Initializing to literal zero makes semantic sense when you want to do a mathematical operation on the integer, and that operation needs to start with the variable being the specific value of zero. A good example would be creating an index counter variable; you want to start with zero and count up.

```
int i = default(int);
```

Setting a variable to its `default` value makes sense when you're, for example, creating a class with said variable where you know the variable will be manually set later on in the process. Here's an example (however impractical it may be):

```
class IntegerClass
{
    private int value;

    public IntegerClass(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        this.value = default(int);
    }
}
```

Again, they're technically equal (and in fact will compile to identical [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)) but each provides a different semantic meaning.

Also, using `default` could be required to initialize a variable when using generics.

```
public T SomeOperation<T>()
{
    T value = default(T);

    this.SomeOtherOperation(ref value);

    return T;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only real difference that it will make is the compile-time, so I suppose it would be a milli-milli-milli-milli second faster one way than the other when you press Debug or Compile but as soon as it's compiled, it will be exactly the same as Marlon said

These small changes will only affect your actual programming time so in a broader sense of the term, writing out default(int) is slower than writing 0 and the time you put thought into it took even longer.